# i cant get the program below, please explain

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jcomponent

```
public class aaa {
public static void main(String[] args)
{

bbb b=new bbb();
    b.setVisible(true);
    b.setSize(400, 400);

}

}
class bbb extends JFrame
{
bbb()
{

draw d=new draw();
add(d);
}

}
class draw extends JComponent
{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
    Ellipse2D rect=new Ellipse2D.Double();
    rect.setFrameFromCenter(50,50,70,70);
    g2.draw(rect);
    g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
    g2.fill(rect);
}
}
```

actually, i know this program will generate a frame and draw ellipse inside the rectangle...
my only question is that, when will the method "paintcomponent(Graphics g)" be invoked...
and i know that, it is a method inside "JComponent" but when will it be invoked...please give a brief explanation....

and one more question is that...it has parameter in type "Graphics"....but it has no object created for the class "Graphics", then how can we call its methods(methods in class "Graphics")..

i know this is stupid question, but i know something i have missed in concept...

Comment: It's not a stupid question, but all it shows is that you missed out on some of the tutorials that explains this and more. Please start here: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). More details can be found here: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html). Doing Swing graphics often requires a different way of coding and way of thinking, of breaking some pre-conceived notions, since graphics is often done passively. Check the tutorials, you won't regret doing so.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html

Answer (score 1):

`paintComponent()` is a method in the `JComponent` superclass.

Code in that class will create a `Graphics` object and call your method:

http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/swing/JComponent.java#1054
http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/awt/RepaintArea.java#227

Answer (score 1):

- paintComponent() will be invoked by the system when needed, you don't need to worry about calling it yourself.
- You can use the param g that is passed to call Graphics methods, eg. g.setPaint() etc.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html):

> (...)the painting subsystem will determine that the component is damaged and will ensure that your paintComponent method is invoked.